# Powershell Call Assembly Delegate

Tags: powershell, dll, delegates

I have a dll assembly for our process control application, which I use load inside my **powershell** script.

The DLL contains a Delegate type that I need to use, delegate name is :

```
"X.Y.Delegate"
```

I have an another method in that DLL that should be called this way :

```
Method( delegatetype CallbackMethod)
```

So, I need to :

1. define a delegate in my script of type `"X.Y.Delegate"` for example `$MyDelegate`
2. define a callback method so that it gets invoked when a process event is triggered"

*Note: I'm sorry if my question seems silly, I'm an ABSOLUTE Beginner.*

Comment: What is your actual question? Are you asking how to implement these or for information as to which option is considered better?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I'm using it actually to minimize resources consumption. rather than checking 10000 of tag values every minute, check what have been changed, I can subscribe to an eventhandler, create my own scriptblock to be executed when event occurs. This way I won't scan my 10000 tags, I would be called back whenever something changes.  This is my understanding to the topic, if I'm wrong I'd be grateful if you correct me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

After reading your comment and reading your question more closely, I think you might be looking to utilize asynchronous event handling. Below is an example that listens for events until a timeout is reached and then exits. This example assumes you can change your assembly to add an event.

A class that generates events:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
 public class Class1
 {
  public event EventHandler SomeEvent;

  protected void OnSomeEvent(EventArgs e)
  {
   var someEvent = SomeEvent;

   if (someEvent != null)
   {
    SomeEvent(this, e);
   }
 }

 public void SomeMethod()
 {
  Task.Run(() =>
  {
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    OnSomeEvent(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
   });
  }
 }
}
```

Powershell:

```
# Load up your .net assembly
add-type -path .\Class1.cs 

$x = new-object ClassLibrary1.Class1

$sourceIdentifier = "SomeEvent"

# Register event
$eh = Register-ObjectEvent -SourceIdentifier $sourceIdentifier -InputObject $x -EventName SomeEvent

$x.SomeMethod()

while ($true)
{
 Write-Host "Waiting for event..."
 $event = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier $sourceIdentifier -Timeout 10

 if ($event -eq $null) 
 {
  Write-Host "No event received for 10 seconds." 
  break 
 }

 # Do processing here
 Write-Host "Processing event..."
 $event

 # Remove event from queue
 Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier $sourceIdentifier
}

Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $sourceIdentifier
Write-Host "Done processing events."
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it DOES work. The idea I think is the variable "ScriptBlock" that encapsulates the block to be executed. I got Powershell stops responding when My application starts calling back the scriptblock, but I can see now in my application server log that handler starts, a handler object is sent, means that I'm on the right direction. Could you please tell me how can powershell responds to my application callbacks after the script has been executed ? I run the script on ISE, debug, when my application server calls me back powershell stops. should I see the output in my console ? Thanks

Comment: @AhmedAtef - Updated based on your comments.